# Routing over a VMware centos server running Cisco VPN

Tags: centos, routing, vmware-fusion

I need help routing over a virtual server to a IPSec tunnel.

I have:

Mac OS laptop (10.20.4.0/24)

VMware Fusion

Centos running on VMware (192.168.141.0/24) that has a Cisco IPSec tunnel (10.255.254.0/24)

Remote servers on the other side of the tunnel. (10.0.11.0/24)

The Cisco IPSec Tunnel is up.

I want my mac to access the remote servers over the tunnel.

I have turned on routing on the centos server.  I have added a static route on the mac pointing at 192.168.141.137 (centos server) for the remote servers (10.0.11.0/24).  What other changes do I need to make for this routing?

Answer (score 1):

The VPN head-end would need a route back to your Mac's IP (10.20.4.x) which the Centos box would need to send via the Mac's 192.168.141.x address - unless you have some kind of masquerading / NAT setup on the Centos side.

Generally Cisco has good support on the native Mac side for VPN access, however - particularly the OS X native IPSEC client (at least since 10.6).  If you're not trying for some specific lab setup I'd suggest simplifying the whole thing.

Comment: Cisco doesn't support 64 bit Mac OS yet, so I can't use that.

I would like the centos server to NAT the source IP of my laptop.  This would allow the routing.

Comment: You don't need the Cisco client - the built-in client in OS X works well.  I've been using it for the past year or so.